# Delaying print job in Windows

Tags: windows, printing

Right now I often print a lot of pages. About 100-200 pages front and back. Is there a tool or something I can do to add a delay between N-pages when printing on windows to rest the printer cartrigde? I'm using Canon MP 287 (Canon using thermal print)

Comment: Which program are you using? Word? Excel?

Comment: I print PDF. I've search to customize print spooler but no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be tedious but maybe.

1. Set the print queue to pause.
2. Print in number of pages of delay, in batches
    say 1-10, then 11-20, 21-30, and etc
3. Pause all the jobs
4. Resume the queue with the jobs still paused.

prnjobs,vbs is included with at least windows 7 and 10
C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US>cscript prnjobs.vbs

list all jobs
cscript prnjobs.vbs -l

Then resume one batch at a time.
cscript prnjobs.vbs -j  -p  -m

A copy of prnjobs.vbs could be made under a new name and modified.

```
Modify to automatically list all jobs
Resume 1
Sleep for ### seconds
resume next job
Repeat
```